# Why (cf)' = c(f)'

Tags: calculus

Why

> $(cf)' = c(f)'$

but not

> $(cf)' = (c)' (f)' = 0 f = 0$

?

Comment: Applying product rule makes the c' term 0.

Comment: Related: [How to prove that $\frac{d}{dx}\epsilon x^2=2\varepsilon x$ where $\varepsilon$ is just a constant](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/770214/85969).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the formula for the derivative of a product is
$$g'\!f+gf'$$
Which gives you $c'\!f+cf'=0+cf'=cf'.$

Comment: Oh, yeah, I'm confused multiplication and addition formula. ._. Thanks for fast answer!

Answer (score 5):

There many different ways to show this.
$$ (cf)'=\frac{d}{dx}[cf(x)] =\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{cf(x+h)-cf(x)}{h}=c \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=c \frac{d}{dx}[f(x)] =cf'$$